# What is the meaning of (,${project.version}] in Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, build-dependencies

I have seen the value `(,${project.version}]` in the version element of maven dependencies. Do these parenthesis and comma mean anything special that make it different from just `${project.version}`?

Comment: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges

Comment: Usually it is not neccesary to use version ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that means the version of that dependency must fall in the range `(,${project.version}]`. Which means its version cannot be higher than `${project.version}`.

See: http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/resolve-ranges.html.